# How to set up multiple Github deployment keys (npm, yarn)?

Tags: git, github, ssh, npm, yarnpkg

I have an npm project that depends on several private Github repositories. I am deploying the project on staging server, and I have set up separate deploy keys for each private repository, as Github does not allow to use the same key for each. I have set up ~/.ssh/config like this:

```
Host 1.github.com
        HostName github.com
        User git
        PreferredAuthentications publickey
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key-1
        StrictHostKeyChecking no

Host 2.github.com
        HostName github.com
        User git
        PreferredAuthentications publickey
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key-2
        StrictHostKeyChecking no

Host 3.github.com
        HostName github.com
        User git
        PreferredAuthentications publickey
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key-3
        StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

In package.json, I have the following private Github repository dependencies:

```
"project1": "git+ssh://git@github.com/myorg/project1.git",
"project2": "git+ssh://git@github.com/myorg/project2.git",
"project3": "git+ssh://git@github.com/myorg/project3.git"
```

However, this does not work and I'm getting `Permission denied (publickey)` error. The projects are also being used by users who access the repositories with their Github accounts.

How do I get the keys working?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use different keys for different github accounts, you need to modify the git urls by using the alias defined in the configuration files, such as:

```
"project1": "git+ssh://git@1.github.com/myorg/project1.git",
"project2": "git+ssh://git@2.github.com/myorg/project2.git",
"project3": "git+ssh://git@3.github.com/myorg/project3.git"
```

Comment: That is not possible, as those keys are not used by everyone who uses the project. It's impractical to commit such environment-specific paths to package.json.

Comment: In that case you will have to modify that on your own or you will have to adjust the project structure. Note that unless you will change the repositpry url, git will not know what key to use. Other possibility would be to use GIT_SSH_COMMAND env. variable with the settings for separate prijects.

Comment: How do you set up GIT_SSH_COMMAND for each project? Also, is it not possible to have a list of keys which would be tried sequentially?

Comment: No idea how to do that in npm. You can have the list, but always the first will succeed if they are recognized by github.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is coming along to this question later on:

It's important to note [@Kitanotori](https://stackoverflow.com/users/692785/kitanotori)'s comment about [@Jakuje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2196426/jakuje)'s answer, you'd have to set up custom ssh configurations on every developer's computer, which is an annoying extra step.

The way I decided to solve the issue is to use the `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` environment variable.

- Assume a node project sitting in a repo: ProjectA
- Assume two more
  projects sitting in their own repos: ProjectB and ProjectC
- Assume we
  want to import both ProjectB and Project C as github-hosted npm
  packages into ProjectA

For local development, every developer should have SSH read and write access to their own Github account, so there should be no issues running npm install and both ProjectB and ProjectC will download successfully.

For a deployment, we want to use deployment keys instead of any one developer's personal key.

Here's the trick: put both ProjectB and ProjectC into the [optionalDependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json#optionaldependencies) of your package.json of ProjectA

In your deployment script, run

```
npm ci --omit=optional
```

This will install all of your dependencies except your personal Github dependencies (ProjectB and ProjectC)

Then run:

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i pathToYourProjectBDeployKey'
```

Then,

```
npm i ProjectB
```

Then similarly for ProjectC:

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i pathToYourProjectCDeployKey'
npm i ProjectC
```

Now your `node_modules` folder will hold all of your dependencies for your deployment!

It's important to note that usually your `package-lock.json` file holds the exact commit that an external git dependency most recently installed, and this method will always install the most recent commit regardless of your `package-lock.json` file. You may want to tweak this method according to your needs.